# Play cue in a row XNA

Tags: c#, xna

When I'm playing cue by `cue.Play()` only one sound is playing.
How can I play all the sounds in the cue one by the other?

Thank ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/95150/568941.aspx) post on App Hub seems to me to be the answer you're looking for.

> Instead of trying to add multiple Sounds to one Cue you have to add multiple wave files to one Track of a Sound and then add that one sound to its own Cue.

Hope this helps!